# How to use a dictionary to create a condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, conditional-statements

Sorry if this sounds uncomplicated but I'm new to Python.

If a child's score is greater or equal than 100 they should get 8 presents; if a child's score is between 50 and 100 they get 5 presents while if a child's score is below 50 then they get 2 presents.

How would I use my dictionary to check whether the users' input was correct?

It would first display their score like:

```
presents=[]
People={"Dan":22,
        "Matt":54,
        "Harry":78,
        "Bob":91}

def displayMenu():
    print("1. Add presents")
    print("2. Quit")
    choice = int(input("Enter your choice : "))
    while 2< choice or choice< 1:
        choice = int(input("Invalid. Re-enter your choice: "))
    return choice

def addpresents():
    name= input('Enter child for their score: ')
    if name == "matt".title():
        print(People["Matt"])
    if name == "dan".title():
        print(People["Dan"])
    if name == "harry".title():
        print(People["Harry"])
    if name == "bob".title():
        print(People["Bob"])
    present=input('Enter number of presents you would like to add: ')
    if present
        #This is where I got stuck

option = displayMenu()

while option != 3:
    if option == 1:
       addpresents()
    elif option == 2:
        print("Program terminating")

option = displayMenu()
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What is `present`? Is it the number of presents you want to give the child? If so, then why is it there if you have predefined amounts of presents to give them?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. Take another look at your question and try to restate clearly what it is exactly you are having an issue with.

Comment: If the number of presents is to be determined by the child's score, why are you asking the user to `Enter number of presents you would like to add: `?

Comment: Duplicate of [_Using a dictionary to validate the users choice_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511129/using-a-dictionary-to-validate-the-users-choice)

Answer (score 0):

Related to the question asked:

> If a child's score is greater or equal than 100 they should get 8 presents; if a child's score is between 50 and 100 they get 5 presents while if a child's score is below 50 then they get 2 presents.

Create a dictionary where the keys are the boolean conditions for the score. But the dictionary has to be re-created each time since `score` is used in it's keys and score can be different for each cycle.

```
>>> score = 3
>>> presents = {score < 50: 2,
...             50 <= score < 100: 5,
...             score >= 100: 8
...             }[True]
>>> presents
2
>>> # and keep re-doing the 3 statements for each score.
```

Effectively, each dictionary key becomes `True` or `False` with only one ever evaluating to `True`. So fetching the value of the *key* `True` gives the number of presents.

Putting that into function makes more sense, like:

```
def get_presents(score):
    return {score < 50: 2,
            50 <= score < 100: 5,
            score >= 100: 8
            }[True]
```

And use it like so:

```
>>> get_presents(25)
2
>>> get_presents(50)
5
>>> get_presents(100)
8
>>>
```

As for the code you've used, that's seems quite far from the intent in the question.

Alternatively, you could do `int(score/50)` as the keys:

```
>>> present_dict = {1: 2,
...                 2: 5,
...                 3: 8
...                 }
>>>
>>> score = 500
>>> present_dict[min(int(score / 50) + 1, 3)]  # needed to not go over 3
8
>>> score = 25
>>> present_dict[min(int(score / 50) + 1, 3)]  # the +1 needed since it's int div
2
>>> # or put the expression above in the `get_presents` function and return that
```